# What are the prerequisites for installing CDO.DLL in Windows Server 2012 for VB application

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2012, mapi, cdo.message

I am upgrading a server from Windows 2003 to 2012 R2. 
One of our VB6 applications used CDO.dll for MAPI, i.e. for sending mails.

My question is :

1. How do I install/register CDO.DLL?
2. What are the prerequisites for installing CDO.DLL?
3. Do I need to install Outlook in my server for the application to send mail?

```
Set objMAPI = New MAPI.Session
objMAPI.Logon ShowDialog:=False, NewSession:=False, ProfileInfo:=gobjINI.gstrExchangeServer & vbLf & gobjINI.gstrProfile
'Add a new mesage to the OUtbo Messages Collection
Set objMSG = objMAPI.Outbox.Messages.Add
'Add the recipient list specified in INI File
'Check if this is a multiple Recipient List (names or groups seperated by semicolons!)
If InStr(1, Recipients, ";") Then
  objMSG.Recipients.AddMultiple Recipients, CdoTo
  objMSG.Recipients.Resolve
Else
  'This section is for handling of single recipient name
  'Be aware that this may be an email group list name !
  Set objRecipients = objMSG.Recipients.Add(Recipients)
  objRecipients.Resolve
End If

'Add Subject Line, Message Content and Send Message
objMSG.Subject = Subject
objMSG.Text = Message

'The Update method adds all our assignments to collecttion
objMSG.Update

'Now let's actually send the message
objMSG.Send

'End MAPI Session
objMAPI.Logoff
Set objMAPI = Nothing

MailSend = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDO 1.21 is no longer being developed or supported by Microsoft. You can download the standalone version of MAPI along with CDO 1.21 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42040. It was last updated in 2014 and no new bug fixes are expected. Functionality wise it has not been updated for the last 15 years.

You can switch to the Outlook Object Model ([Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869848.aspx) object roughly corresponds to the `MAPI.Session` object).

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - its [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object is similar to the `MAPI.Session` object (with a lot more extra features).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. So to work with MAPI do we need MS Outlook. MAPI function is to send receive mail, so can it work without MS Outlook.

Comment: You can install the standalone version of MAPI but it won' do you any good since there won't be any existing profiles, and you wouldn't be able to connect to Exchange 2013 or 2016,.

Comment: Ok so outlook installation is must to work with MAPI?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. If you only want to work with an older version of Exchange, or to process ANSI PST or MSG files, it will work,.

Comment: As you can see in the code above , we are using CDO 1.2.1 to send mails.
SO > do i have to install Outlook? And  > I am new to this exchange server, do i need to install it seperately too?.

Comment: Your code is creating a dynamic temporary profile that points to the specified Exchange server (gobjINI.gstrExchangeServer) and the mailbox (gobjINI.gstrProfile). In case of the Outlook Object Model your only option is to create a profile that connects to that mailbox and log to that profile using Namespace.Logon. In case of Redemption (which is a lot closer to CDO 1.21 than OOM) you can use RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox (Exchange 2010 or older) or  RDOSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox (Exchange 2013/2016).

Comment: Ok got it so if i will go with OOM i have to install Outlook? And one more thing,CDO 1.21 doesn't require Outlook just exchange server will do, can you plese verify it?

Comment: Yes, Outlook must be installed if you want to use the Outlook Object Model. Outlook also installs the Extended MAPI system. The standalone install of CDO 1.21 and MAPI does not require Outlook, but as I previously mentioned, you will not be able to connect to Exchange 2013 or 2016.

Comment: thanks so much for showing the right direction here. I think as of now i am good installing CDO 1.21 and MAPI(which will not require Outlook). To install MAPI, i need to know the version of exchange server installed. Neither Exchange Server Client Or Outlook is installed, do you have any idea how can check it's version?

Comment: Since you know the server name, can you ask the Exchange admin?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for all your suggestions.